# Searching External Content in SharePoint Online and SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-search

I am attempting to determine SP Search capabilities in SP Online vs SharePoint 2019 on-prem.  Specifically, around searching/crawling external content in a custom database/tables or file share.  Does SP Online offer this?  Any gotchas or restrictions vs SP 2019 on-prem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this up in SPO via Microsoft Search [Graph connectors](https://docs.microsoft.com/microsoftsearch/connectors-overview). This is the modern method to implement this versus the classic SharePoint Search-based method of doing so in SharePoint Server.

Microsoft Graph connector results will not be available via Hybrid Search, if that is an important consideration.